# Keycloak Rest API get all available resources

Tags: php, rest, curl, keycloak, openid

i am trying to list all resources client have access to. I am unable to figure out how to to make the call. I have used this curl

```
curl -X GET \
  http://$URL/auth/realms/$RELM/authz/resource-server/resource \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer$TOKEN' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

so far but i am getting this response :
{"error":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8070/auth/realms/argo/authz/resource-server/resource"}

Can someone help me to figure out how i can list all resources and if resource is not in the list to create new one ?

---

SOLUTION that is implementd:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->keyCloakURL . '/realms/' . $this->relmName . '/protocol/openid-connect/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "audience=" . KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_NAME . "&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket&response_include_resource_name=true");
    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer " . $user_token['access_token'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            $authorization
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'curl error';
        return false;
    }
    
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(isset($result['access_token']) && !empty($result['access_token']))
    {
        $parts = explode('.', $result['access_token']);
        if(!isset($parts[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $info = $this->base64UrlDecode($parts[1]);
        $info = json_decode($info, true);
        
        $return = array ();
        if(isset($info['authorization']['permissions']))
        {
            $permissions = $info['authorization']['permissions'];
            foreach($permissions as $ecahPermission)
            {
                if(isset($ecahPermission['scopes']))
                {
                    //                      $scopes = array_map('strtolower', $ecahPermission['scopes']);
                    $return[$ecahPermission['rsname']] = $ecahPermission['scopes'];
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $return;
    }
    
    return false;
```

Comment: Try to invoke is '../authz/protection/resource_set' (cfr https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/service/protection/resources-api-papi.html)

Comment: Thanks @TacheDeChoco i also found the solution and it works. Now i have problem to create user policy and update resource to add this created user policy to permission. Also this calls needs to be made by rest api. Do you know how to deal with this ?

Comment: @ViktorPeshevski can you please share the solution if you found it

Comment: @RavinderPayal sure i updated my question with PHP solution

Comment: Thanks, @ViktorPeshevski!

 $user_token['access_token'] is coming from frontend?

If yes, how are you sourcing this access token? by directly calling the keycloak API from frontend using a public client or via a resource server after including a confidential client key/secret?

Comment: This is actual token after logging in user to your application with client from keycloak as mediator

Comment: @ViktorPeshevski any chance we can have quick chat, got many questions? If yes please share your LinkedIn or Twitter. I am facing authorisation denied issues when using token coming along request from front-end client(public-client)

Comment: @ViktorPeshevski The client mediating in the keycloak is public one?

Comment: @RavinderPayal the client is confidential